# How do Vulcans reproduce themselves given that they are emotionless?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Since Vulcans are emotionless, how do they get into the mood for sex?

**How do they solve the problem of reproduction when sex is not possible?**

Comment: Continuation of the species is logical.

Comment: "No husband can get his wife pregnant if he cannot become aroused." [citation needed]. It would seem that [testicular sperm extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testicular_sperm_extraction) and some form of in-vitro fertilization works completely without any arousal.

Comment: I can think of one reason for the down vote, Vulcans are far from emotionless. They have to actively repress their emotion. And when it won't be repressed anymore, their emotions can be quite empassioned and/or explosive.

Comment: Vulcans aren't emotionless. They regularly suppress emotions.

Comment: This is supposed to be a place where people can share information.  I'm confused why you're getting so many downvotes.  I understand that this is explained thouroughly in various series, but I don't see that as a reason for this question to be downvoted.  I'm sorry you've run into such an issue here. +1

Comment: This question is getting downvotes because it is based on a couple of incorrect premises: "you cannot get pregnant without arousal" and "Vulcans are emotionless".

Comment: Yes, those both seem possible reasons for a downvote -- especially the former.  The question assumes that emotion is required for sex.  Even among emotional and non-fictional humans, physical arousal can be, well, purely physical, without any emotional content.  The underlying mechanisms involved are reflexes.  They are responses to stimulation.  Other human reflexes that often respond to emotional stimuli (e.g. dilated pupils, goosebumps, etc.) do not *require* emotion to operate.  Lack of emotion should not suggest that sex is difficult, let alone impossible.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a misconception among fans that Vulcans only mate during the [Pon Farr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pon_farr#cite_note-1), a seven-yearly ritual in which they must mate or die (seen in the episodes [TOS: Amok Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amok_Time) and [Voy: Blood Fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Fever_(Star_Trek:_Voyager))).

Trek writer Dorothy C. Fontana stated in an interview (for [Captains' Logs: The Unauthorized Complete Trek Voyages](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captains'_Logs:_The_Unauthorized_Complete_Trek_Voyages)) that **Vulcans are both capable and willing to have sex outside of this period, presumably for the purposes of procreation and also to cement emotional closeness:**

> ***"Vulcans mate normally any time they want to.*** However, every seven
>   years you do the ritual, the ceremony, the whole thing. The biological
>   urge. You must, but any other time is any other emotion—humanoid
>   emotion—**when you're in love. When you want to, you know when the urge
>   is there, you do it.** This every-seven-years business was taken too
>   literally by too many people who don't stop and understand. We didn't
>   mean it only every seven years. I mean, every seven years would be a
>   little bad, and it would not explain the Vulcans of many different
>   ages which are not seven years apart".

The other misconception is that Vulcans are **emotionless**. Note that every Vulcan we see in the show is *struggling* to keep their (ultra-strong) emotions in check. When this mental control fails, they generally go berserk.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph, this was my immediate thought. Vulcans spend many years of intensive training learning how to control their emotions, that doesn't mean they don't feel them. Also, Pon Farr shows up (albeit briefly) in STIII:The Search For Spock too.

Answer (score 4):

Vulcans have emotions, very strong and intensely felt; this is repeatedly affirmed throughout the various series, most pointedly in the TNG episode "Sarek".  And Vulcans have sex for recreational purposes as well as procreative (T'Pol and Trip got it on a few times in ENT IIRC).

Vulcans used to be savage and warlike, far worse than humans ever were, such that they nearly wiped themselves out without the need for WMDs; Surak recognized that Vulcans would not survive unless they found a way to supress most emotional reactions, hence the philosophy of pure logic (again, multiple episodes - "The Savage Curtain", "All Our Yesterdays" from TOS are the ones that come to mind immediately).

Secondly, arousal and emotional response are not necessarily the same thing.  Biological imperatives will win out over philosophy.  Pon Farr is the price Vulcans pay for keeping their emotions so tightly bottled up.

Answer (score 3):

Every seven years they go mad with emotion and must return to their birthplace so they can mate. See "Amok Time", Original Star Trek series.

Answer (score 1):

Vulcans have emotions, pretty volatile ones, but since the times of Surak they try (with more or less success individually) to control their emotional responses by using logic. Only a master of the Kolinaar is without emotions, but they are a minority.
Vulcans are capable to have sex and procreate like any other biological being. The "Pon Farr" is a distinctive feature of the species, with chemical imbalances in the brain that will shatter the logical control. Either sex or fight is used to purge the chemicals out of the body and return to a state of equibrilium.